# Next.js dynamic path forever loading (hangs)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fastify, fastify-nextjs

Today I started writing a small Next.js app. I'm running a custom server using Fastify and the `@fastify/nextjs` plugin, but am running into issues loading dynamic routes.

Here's a snippet of my `index.ts`:

```
// ... Imports above

export const PORT = +(process.env.PORT ?? 3000);

run(async () => {
    // Initialize Fastify
    const app = fastify({ logger: true, pluginTimeout: 20e3 });

    // Initialize Apollo
    const apollo = new ApolloServer({
        typeDefs,
        resolvers,
        csrfPrevention: true,
        cache: 'bounded',
        plugins: [fastifyAppClosePlugin(app), ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer: app.server })],
    });

    console.log('Registering Fastify plugins.');
    // ... Register helmet, compression, cookie, and session plugins

    console.log('Registering Fastify Next.js plugin.');
    // Make Fastify work with Next.js
    await app.register(nextJSPlugin, { dev: true });
    // Make Fastify serve up all Next.js pages
    app.next('*');

    console.log('Starting Apollo server.');
    // Start the Apollo server
    await apollo.start();
    // Make Fastify handle GraphQL requests
    app.register(apollo.createHandler());

    console.log(`Waiting for connection to MongoDB at ${MONGODB_URI}`);
    await mongoConnection.asPromise();

    console.log('Starting the server...');
    // Start the Fastify server
    app.listen({ port: PORT }, () => {
        console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
        console.log(`GraphQL endpoint: ${apollo.graphqlPath}`);
    });
});
```

The pages for the Next.js app load perfectly fine except for the dynamic routes. I have pages on `/` and `/test`, which both work fine. But on this route `[slug]`, the browser just hangs forever.

Here's what `[slug].tsx` looks like:

```
import { GetStaticPaths, GetStaticProps } from 'next';
import React from 'react';
// Configured Apollo client
import { client } from '../apollo/client';
import { PAGES } from '../apollo/queries';
import { PageType } from '../server/models/types';

type PageProps = {
    slug: string;
    content: string;
};

const Slug = ({ slug, content }: PageProps) => {
    return <div>thank god it loaded</div>;
};

export default Slug;

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
    const { data } = await client.query<{ pages: PageType[] }>({
        query: PAGES,
    });

    return {
        // The routes supported here are defined by the records in the "Pages" collection in my database
        paths: data.pages.filter(({ slug }) => slug !== '/').map(({ slug }) => ({ params: { slug } })),
        fallback: false,
    };
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
    const { slug } = params as { slug: string };

    const { data } = await client.query<{ pages: [PageType] }>({
        query: PAGES,
        variables: {
            slug,
        },
    });

    return {
        props: data.pages[0],
        revalidate: 30,
    };
};
```

1. I've ensured that my GraphQL server is running and healthy - the `pages` query works totally fine in Postman, Insomnia, and with cURL.
2. I've triple checked and made sure that I initialized Apollo Client correctly. It is successfully connecting to the GraphQL server.

What could the issue be? Is it my file structure? Here's a rundown of what that looks like:

```
 - index.ts
 - /server
   - /config
   - /schemas
   - /models
   - /utils
 - /pages
  - _app.tsx
  - index.ts
  - [slug].tsx
```

I'm also using `ts-node` to ... yup, that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the command `nodemon --exec ts-node-esm index.ts` to run the code, but I'm not using ESModules in my project anymore, so while typing this question I switched it to `nodemon --exec ts-node index.ts` and the page loads.

The reason (I believe) is because behind the scenes Next.js dynamically imports the `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths` functions from your component, and imports work differently between CommonJS and ESModules.

Spent an hour trying to solve this, wow.

Comment: then by using get static props and get static paths , you were able to see load time faster

Comment: @AdarshRaj Nope that's not the reason.

Comment: I have been trying to speed up dev time, every route jump,new complilation after a change takes lot of time